# How can I set the background of a slide with a background image?

Tags: beamer, color

I have a background image for one of my slides which is partially transparent. I'd like to set the background color for this slide to black, but it does not work.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{muon1.png}}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: muon1.png]

Comment: Please, next time propose a complete MWE, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. And if you can, provide a transparent image. This way will be easier to test your code and help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use the `background` template for the image and `background canvas` for the black background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{muon1.png}}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 A better solution than the one I proposed... ;-)